# Support direct linking to react-router paths with nginx on local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, nginx, react-router

I'm trying to set up a local react and rails environment.  My react app is currently hosted at `http://localhost:8080` and my rails app at `http://localhost:3000`.  I'd like to have these both served from the same url, like `http://localhost:9999`.

The basics of this is working like:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 9999;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }

    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is pasting a route into the address bar other than `/` will not work -- a common problem.

So, a common answer is to change the `location /` rule to look more like this:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /client/index.html
}
```

However, that gives me the error:

> rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/client/index.html"

which makes sense, but I don't know how to get around it.

My directory structure:

```
root/
 - app/ (rails app)
 - client/ (react app, currently served by webpack-dev-server)
   - index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite old question but I had the same problem and finally managed to solve it.

In my case the following configuration did the job:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

Just point `root` to the location with your WWW files.